# Does Ionic and React Native apps run on node server in Android and iOS devices?

Tags: node.js, react-native, ionic-framework, webpack-dev-server, hybrid-mobile-app

I am confused how hybrid apps work on Android and iOS devices. Do they install local node or webpack server? And for each hybrid app there is its own server? So how actually these apps work?

I am new in Ionic app development. I just built a simple ionic app and install its apk on my Android phone but i am getting this:

**Webpage not available**

The webpageat http://localhost:8100/ could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

---

And a popup with following content:

**Application Error**

### net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8100/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ionic and React Native are two very different things.

Ionic generates a hybrid app. This is a native app but the native app is just a shell with a mini-webserver and a webview control. Your app is served by the mini-webserver and runs in the webview control. Basically it is still a webapp and not a true native app. See [this article](https://ionicframework.com/resources/articles/what-is-hybrid-app-development) for more details.

The above is true for all variants of Ionic: Angular, React and Vue.

React Native generates a true native app. There is no webserver or webview control involved.

[This article](https://ionicframework.com/resources/articles/ionic-react-vs-react-native) describes the differences in more detail.

Comment: Ionic app runs on a mini-webserver so each ionic app has its own webserver? And apk contain webserver too?

Comment: Then it is not waste of resources? Is it not possible to have one server for all such apps?

Comment: Not really, because it is not a full fledged web server like Apache. Having a self-contained app that is separate from other apps is much more important.

Comment: Yes understand. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Alright. If this answers your question, consider marking this answer as accepted.